# Opencv Inpaint for CV_32FC1?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Seems [Inpaint](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) in OpenCV can accept only 8UC1 images.

Is there exist Inpaint for CV_32FC1 images in OpenCV? Or there is some workaround how it can be used for CV_32FC1 images? Or is there any analogue of this function?

Answer (score 1):

Inpaint still don't support float32 data. The issue is open state (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4542).

You can use the code below as an alternative.

```
src32f.convertTo(src8b, CV_8U, 255.0f/max, min);

inpaint(src8b, mask, dst8b, inpaintRadius, flags);

dst8b.convertTo(dst32f, CV_32F, max/255.0f, -min);

//optional, copy only inpainted data
mask.convertTo(mask, CV_32F, 1 / 255.0f);
dst32f = src32 + (dst32f - src32).mul(mask);
```